# Why is $\tan^{-1}(0)=0$?

Tags: trigonometry

My calculator tells me that $\tan^{-1}(0)=0$.

If $\tan^{-1}(\theta)=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$ and $\cos0=1$ and $\sin0=0$, then $\tan^{-1}(0)=\frac{\cos0}{\sin0}=\frac{1}{0}$ and should be undefined, right?

What am I missing here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: $tan^{-1} \theta$ refers to the arctangent function (the inverse function), not the reciprocal.

Comment: Do you mean $(\tan \theta)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\tan \theta}$, the reciprocal of the tangent function, or do you mean $\arctan \theta = \tan^{-1} \theta$, the inverse of the tangent function?

Comment: $$(\tan\theta)^{-1}\not=\tan^{-1}\theta$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing $\tan^{-1}(x)$ with $\cot(x)$, the cotangent function. $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is equivalent to $\arctan(x)$, the function which takes an angle $x$ and maps it back to the "ratio of sides" (opposite over adjacent in a right triangle) which corresponds to it. So $\tan(x) = \frac {\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, $\cot(x) = \frac {\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$, and then by its definition, $(\arctan \circ \tan)(x) = x$. Note that in composition notation, $(\arctan \circ \tan)(x) = x$ means that we evaluate $\tan(x)$ first and then apply $\arctan(x)$ to it.

Also, see Horacio's post for a more concise statement.

Comment: Yes, I was confusing inverse tangent/arctangent with cotangent.

Comment: As for which answer to choose. I thought both answers were very helpful - the helpful explanation and the concise equations really complement each other.

Comment: It is not correct that $\arctan(x)\circ\tan(x)=x$.  Rather, it is correct that $(\arctan\circ\tan)(x)=x$.  One composes the functions, not the _values_ of the functions. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You're correct, edited for accuracy- let me know if you notice other errors.

Answer (score 4):

$y = \tan^{-1} (x) $ iff $\tan y = x $

So,if $x = 0 $, this is same as asking when is $\tan y = 0 $. In other words,

$$ \frac{ \sin y}{\cos y} = 0 \iff \sin y = 0 \iff y = 0 (\mod \pi)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

In an accident of history, the notation $f^n(x)$ had been adopted by two branches of mathematics to mean somewhat different things.

Set theorists adopted the convention of using $f^n(x)$ to mean **composition**, so that $f^2(x)= (f\circ f)(x) = f(f(x))$ and so on.   Almost at the same time Geometric theorists meanwhile began using the same notation to mean **exponentiation**, so that $f^2(x) = f(x)\cdot f(x)$ and such.   Neither wanted to give up the nice compact notation, so they both continued using it their own way.

While the notation is now *mostly* used to mean exponentiation, it is *still* used for composition in certain works.   Some authors will adopt a compromise and use $f^{\circ n}$ to be clear that they mean composition; but others will merely rely on you reading their notes carefully.

More confusingly, even when $f^n(x)$ means the exponentiation of the function, there is this one exception.   The accepted convention is that the notation $f^{-1}(x)$ *always* means the *composition* inverse; rather than the exponential inverse as might be expected.

---

**tl;dr**  $\tan^{-1}(x)$ does not mean the exponential inverse $\frac 1{\tan(x)}$, instead it means the composition inverse, which is $\arctan(x)$.

Comment: You wrote "convolution" when you mean "composition".  I've fixed the typo. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  Thank you.